# Json JQuery error for no reason

Tags: json, model-view-controller

I get an with no description from ajax:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script  type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'http://www.ouzhat.com/madad/api/adsapi',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (data) {

           },
           error: function (x,y,z) {
               alert(x+'\n'+y+'\n'+z);
           }
       });
        });
</script>
```

This is my webapp method code:

```
public JsonResult get() {
    return new JsonResult() {
        Data=ADS.SelectAll(),
        JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is cross domain issue (Please read on internet about it for further clarification).

if ajax and service file is on same domain then remove http://www.ouzhat.com from URl and provide local reference.

Another way is to add header [ header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); (example of PHP)] to your service file.